# Locating element in Xcode UI Test without accessiblity id

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest, ios-ui-automation

Recently I started learning XCode UI Test to write functional automation tests using UI testing feature of Xcode.

I need to read a text value of native app element. I can get the element with the  help of text of element but the problem is I can not use the text as it is dynamic it will be changed after some time or next launch of app.

I am familiar with using WebDriver and Appium where I can tackle this with writing parent - child xpath.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem? Please post a sample code snippet as well with your solution as I am new to apple technology / swift.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your app's code, add an accessibility identifier to the element you want to inspect, then use that identifier to find the element in your UI test code.

```
// app code
let myLabel = UILabel()
myLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = "myDescriptionLabel"
// add other label configuration...

// UI test code
let app = XCUIApplication()
let descriptionLabel = app.staticTexts["myDescriptionLabel"]
let description = descriptionLabel.value as String
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but problem is I am not allowed to change development code. and there are many elements which do not have accessiblityIdentifier. (it is "empty") so just trying to find out any other way around. I know i can use decendentsMatching or containg... but with is not that user friendly. I feel appium locators specially Xpath is far better.

Comment: You can pretty much do the same thing as Xpath, although this is a very brittle technique and in order to make your app properly testable, the developers really should invest a few minutes in adding accessibility IDs. You can use things like `app.staticTexts.element(boundBy: 2)` to get the third label on the screen, or narrow it down by the view hierarchy for example, the first label in the second table cell: `app.tables.element(boundBy: 0).cells.element(boundBy: 1).staticTexts.element(boundBy: 0)`